# SharePoint 2013 - Error “init.js failed to load”

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-2013

I am new to SharePoint 2013 server and SharePoint designer 2013. When I browse SharePoint site in IE, I am getting the below error.

```
"init.js failed to load"
```

But when I browse SharePoint site in chrome, it is working fine.

Can any one help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

I have run the Office Diagnostic Tool from my PC. and issue is resolved.

Link : http://sharepointnuke.blogspot.in/2012/05/initjs-error-with-internet-explorer.html